# Converting a String to hex and calculate binary result in python

Tags: c#, python, binary, hex, distance

I got stuck with my code, tried anything on this side and many other things Google showed.

To the problem:

I try to convert some code-snips from C# to phyton, but on this special point i got stuck.

```
public static long decode(string data, int size, int offset = 0)
{
    long value = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i) {
        value <<= 6;
        value |= (long)data[offset + i] - 0x30;
    }

    return value;
}
```

The String Data could be something like `1Dh`. Based on this I convert each char to the hex-equivalent: 0x31, 0x44, 0x68 and subtract 0x30; so I get 0x1, 0x14, 0x38;
In the next step I have to convert to the binary equivalent 000001, 010100, 111000 and merge this to 
000001010100111000. From this I want to get the integer meaning, in this case 5432.

Is there a possibility to do this in a smart and easy way in python?

Comment: The Python functions `ord`, `hex`, and `bin` may be useful to you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's actually pretty easy, and the translation is pretty straight forward. You can continue to use your bit shifting. The only change is the syntax of for-loop and using [`ord()`](https://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#ord) to get the integer value from a character.

```
def decode(data, size, offset=0):
    value = 0

    for ch in data[offset:size]:
        value <<= 6
        value |= ord(ch) - 0x30

    return value
```

Running this in the interpreter, I get `5432`:

```
>>> decode("1Dh", 3)
5432
```